# Composer doesn't load custom repo

Tags: git, composer-php

I forked three coupled repos on github to make changes in one of them and use those changes now, while the PR is not approved. Those repos are:

- https://github.com/viktorprogger/async-soap-guzzle
- https://github.com/viktorprogger/soap-http-binding
- https://github.com/viktorprogger/php-soap-interpreter (here I changed `src/Soap.php`)

In `async-soap-guzzle` and `soap-http-binding` I've added my repos to `composer.json` (and set `dev-master` as a version to use) and so I did with `composer.json` in my project. Now when I use `composer update` in the project it loads the last commit from `master` of the main repo of `async-soap-guzzle` :( Please anybody, explain me why it does so.

Here is my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "name": "arrilot/bitrix-migrations",
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/viktorprogger/bitrix-migrations"
        },
        {
            "name": "meng-tian/async-soap-guzzle",
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/viktorprogger/async-soap-guzzle"
        },
        {
            "name": "meng-tian/async-soap-guzzle",
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/viktorprogger/soap-http-binding"
        },
        {
            "name": "meng-tian/async-soap-guzzle",
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/viktorprogger/php-soap-interpreter"
        }
    ],

    "require": {
        "php": "^5.6",
        "ext-pdo":  "*",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-libxml": "*",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-soap": "*",

        "arrilot/bitrix-migrations": "dev-master",
        "shuchkin/simplexlsx": "^0.8",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.25",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.4",
        "meng-tian/async-soap-guzzle": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Every time a run `composer update` is says `Updating meng-tian/async-soap-guzzle dev-master (dbbc9b2 => 15ec881):  Checking out 15ec881a6e`. `dbbc9b2` is my repo's `master` `HEAD` and `15ec881` is original repo's `master` `HEAD` which is actually checked out every time.

Here is a block from my `composer.lock` about the `async-soap-guzzle` repo:

```
        "name": "meng-tian/async-soap-guzzle",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/viktorprogger/async-soap-guzzle.git",
            "reference": "dbbc9b2e0a0d3f8c201b347c3b2a38f28fe41f5e"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/viktorprogger/async-soap-guzzle/zipball/dbbc9b2e0a0d3f8c201b347c3b2a38f28fe41f5e",
            "reference": "dbbc9b2e0a0d3f8c201b347c3b2a38f28fe41f5e",
            "shasum": ""
        },
```

But code in `vendor` directory corresponds to `dev-master` from the original repo (https://api.github.com/repos/meng-tian/async-soap-guzzle)

Answer (score 0):

Composer will take into account custom repositories only from the root `composer.json`, meaning, you need to add all three custom repositories to your project `composer.json` for Composer to load your forks into your project.

More details here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories

Comment: Thnx, read the doc once again and updated my question. The problem is in the situation that not even one of these three packages downloads from my repos. But there is one more package `arrilot/bitrix-migrations` with a custom repo declared, and it successfully downloads from custom repo.